# Restoring MySQL backup from disk image

Tags: mysql, backup

I recently flubbed a query and nuked a table in MySQL.  I also realized that I don't have a cron doing a nightly SQL dump.  But I do have a nightly disk image, which I've restored and mounted on the DB server.

I found a giant "ibdata1" file in ~/my_restore/var/lib/mysql that sounds like it is probably my database.

Is there a command I can run to do a dump directly from the database file?

Or perhaps I should stop mysql and update /etc/mysql/my.cnf to point to the new datafile?

Just trying to get advice before I compound stupid with more stupid(er).

Comment: How exactly do you capture this disk image?  You stop/pause mysql when taking this disk image right?  If not, then what you may have as part of your backup is a corrupt file.

Comment: Good question.  I'm actually using Linode's (www.linode.com) automated nightly backups, and I'm going to wager they don't stop my database for me.  So it'd be a gamble as to whether the backup is corrupt.   Presuming its not, any suggestions?

Comment: If you can afford downtime, I would just stop the mysql server, move /var/lib/mysql to /var/lib/mysql_production restore what you have on your disk image to /var/lib/mysql and see if your mysql server will start.  If so, then do a mysqldump. Then stop mysql, and move your production database back to /var/lib/mysql.  Just for the sake of safety, you might want to take a mysqldump of your production databases before you start messing around.

Comment: @Zoredache Ok, that makes perfect sense.  I'll give that a try!  If you move your comment to an answer, I'll flag it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off taking a disk image of a running mysql server is almost certain to result in a corrupt backup.  That is a poor backup strategy, and something you should correct ASAP.  Mysqldump is the prefered tool, followed by stopping the mysql server.

In any case the procedure I would follow if I was in your shoes and could afford some downtime would be the following.

- Make a backup of the database as it is right now, using a supported method (don't want to make things even worse during the fix).
- Stop the Mysql server
- Rename the mysql data directory to some temporary location (mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_production)
- Try restoring the data from your disk image to /var/lib/mysql
- Start the mysql server and look for errors
- Make a backup/export of the 'restored' data.
- Switch back to your production databases

  - Stop the server
  - git rid of the restored /var/lib/mysql
  - move /var/lib/mysql_production back to /var/lib/mysql
  - start the mysql server
- Selectively restore the individual tables/data/etc from the export you made of the restored data.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to backup MySQL is with MySQL data exports via `mysqldump`.  Taking an image of the whole server while running will only result in a potentially corrupted server.

So that said, I would suggest the following.

1. Restore the image you have.
2. Once restored, login & run `mysqldump` on the DB in question that was borked.
3. Take that exported MySQL file & re-import it into your working setup.